# Flat Apportionment of values across time periods

Tags: r, data.table

For different values of `id` I have a `start` and `end` dates with a relative quantity, `var`.
For each records (for the same `id`), `start` date is the same then the previous `end` date (here it comes `roll`...).

These periods span across multiple months and possibly years. My need is to split the quantity in `var` into parts relative to the actual days in each months. e.g.

```
start       end         var
30/01/2006  20/02/2006  104
```

above I have 21 days, the lower limit will belong to the previous period and the upper to the current, so 1/21 of 104 will be assigned to Jan 2006 and the rest to Feb 2006

I currently have two methods, listed below with dummy data, but they are pretty slow and I was wondering if someone may help with me out to speed them up.

```
library(data.table)

# data
set.seed(1)
nsample <- 200L  # To increase the data size just change nsample 

dt <- data.table(id= 1L:nsample)
dt <- dt[, list(date=sample(seq(as.Date("2006-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-01"), "day"), 51, F)), by=id]

setkey(dt)
dt <- dt[, {tmp <- embed(as.vector(date), 2);list(start = structure(tmp[,2], class="Date"),
                                                  end   = structure(tmp[,1], class="Date"),
                                                  var   = rnorm(50, 100, 5))}, by=id]
setkey(dt, id, end)

> dt[1:4]
   id      start        end       var
1:  1 2006-01-30 2006-02-20 104.41542
2:  1 2006-02-20 2006-05-15 106.89356
3:  1 2006-05-15 2006-08-21 106.71162
4:  1 2006-08-21 2006-09-30  96.21729

# Method 1

dt1 <- copy(dt)

system.time({
  dt1[, id2 := 1:.N]
  tmp <- dt1[, list(id = id,
                   date = seq(start+1, end, "day"),
                   var = var), by=id2]
  tmp[, var := var/(.N), by=id2]
  res1 <- tmp[, list(var = sum(var)), by=list(id, period = paste(year(date), month(date), sep="-"))]
})

   #user  system elapsed 
   #1.92    0.00    1.92 

# Method 2

dt2 <- copy(dt)

system.time({
  dt2[, Ndays := as.integer(end)-as.integer(start)]
  tmp <- dt2[, list(date = seq(min(start)+1, max(end), "day")), by=id]
  setkey(tmp)
  res2 <- dt2[ tmp, roll=-Inf][ end >= start,list(var = sum(var/Ndays)), by=list(id, period = paste(year(end), month(end), sep="-")) ]
})

   #user  system elapsed 
   # 0.7     0.0     0.7 


> sum(dt$var) == sum(res1$var)
[1] TRUE
> sum(dt$var) == sum(res2$var)
[1] TRUE

> all.equal(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE

> res2[1:4]
   id period        var
1:  1 2006-1   4.972163
2:  1 2006-2 109.623593
3:  1 2006-3  39.448815
4:  1 2006-4  38.176273
```

Comment: `res1` and `res2` are different for me

Comment: oh I see, you have a typo, it should be `end` instead of `start` in the last `by`

Comment: @eddi Yeah I'm sorry. I was using `roll=T` before, which then needs `start`. Forgot to change to `end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a bit faster (it's 3x faster for me than your second version). I optimized several things in your second version, that you can see below:

```
# let's just divide here instead of later
dt2[, var := var/(as.integer(end)-as.integer(start))]
tmp <- dt2[, list(date = seq(min(start)+1, max(end), "day")), by=id]
# data is sorted, so no need to sort again, just set key without sort
setattr(tmp, "sorted", c("id", "date"))

res2 <- dt2[tmp, roll=-Inf][,
            list(var = sum(var)),
            # doing the paste in by slows it down quite a bit, so let's postpone it
            by=list(id, year(end), month(end))][,
            `:=`(period = paste(year, month, sep = '-'), year = NULL, month = NULL)]
```

Re comment about large sizes - you could do all of the above inside `dt2`. It'll be slower, but I it won't create a large `tmp`:

```
dt2[, var := var/(as.integer(end)-as.integer(start))][,
    {tmp = data.table(date = seq(min(start)+1, max(end), "day"));
     setattr(tmp, 'sorted', 'date');
     setattr(.SD, 'sorted', 'end');
     .SD[tmp, roll = -Inf][,
         list(var = sum(var)), by = list(year(end), month(end))][,
         `:=`(period = paste(year, month, sep = '-'), year = NULL, month = NULL)]
    }, by = id]
```

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll check tomorrow at the pc... but I can see the improvements already. Do you think there is a possibility to achive the above, throu method 2 but without defining the sequences for all the ids? Prob it doesn't make so sense cause in that case the roll won't be meaningful

Comment: @Michele I can't think of a way, sorry

Comment: fine, your answer does already help me a lot. I'll just wait before I accept to see if someone else replies too. Anyway, my question in the comment came up cause in the real case doing the sequence for each `id` value leads to `tmp` having 2.19e+10 rows (6e+6 `id` unique values and 10 years data)