# Linearly apportion amounts by month

Tags: r

Please consider the following synthetic data frame:

```
#Learning to enable splitting contributions spanning two months

start = c(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2013-02-01"), as.Date("2013-04-01"), as.Date("2013-04-16"), as.Date("2013-05-16"))
end = c(as.Date("2013-01-31"), as.Date("2013-03-31"), as.Date("2013-04-15"), as.Date("2013-05-15"), as.Date("2013-05-31"))
amount = c(100, 200, 50, 100, 50)

df = data.frame(start,end,amount)
```

This is a list of cash received and the time period it relates to. Some of these time periods span two months. I would like to aggregate this by month. For those amounts that relate to a period which spans two months I would like to linearly apportion / allocate them between the two months.

What would be the idiomatically correct way to go about doing this in R?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flat Apportionment of values across time periods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835463/flat-apportionment-of-values-across-time-periods)

Comment: Thanks Michele. I've read through the answer to the Flat Apportionment question and not entirely sure how I can apply that to my example. I need a little more guidance as I'm quite new to R so also need some idiomatic insight into how "things are done" in the R way of thinking. But thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: In the case of the fourth row, would you want something that allocates $50 to april and $50 to may, or leave that alone since it's total duration is one month?

Comment: @SeñorO: I would like to allocate 50 to April and 50 to May please.

Comment: The code in the answer does exactly what you want. If you can't get it working, please edit your question referring to my question and saying like "this part of the code is not working", and the question won't a duplicate at all! Please note that there are 2 methods to solve your problem in my question, and other 2 (faster) in its answer... so, you have 4 solution already available. I'd says choose the first in the answer from Eddi and post in your question above what does not work

Comment: @Michele Your question loses some readability because of its focus on speed, and it also deals exclusively with `data.table`. This question appears much clearer and simpler, and is more likely to help other users.

Comment: @SeñorO `data.table` is still `R` after all, and (about the readability) I don't see where is the problem in someone spending a bit of time in trying to understand a 5 to 10 line code (perfectly working with **reproducible** example...). I thought that a bit of effort was encouraged by SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function `explode` that explodes an interval into a data frame with one row *per day*.  Use `Map` to apply `explode` to each interval producing a list of data frames, one per interval.  Next `rbind` the data frames in the list into one big data frame, `by.date`, having one row per day.  Finally aggregate `by.date` into one row for each year/month:

```
library(zoo) # as.yearmon

explode <- function(start, end, amount) {
   dates <- seq(start, end, "day")
   data.frame(dates, yearmon = as.yearmon(dates), amount = amount / length(dates))
}
by.date <- do.call("rbind", Map(explode, df$start, df$end, df$amount))
aggregate(amount ~ yearmon, by.date, sum)
```

Using the data in the question (assuming the occurrence of 2010 was supposed to be 2013) we get:

```
   yearmon    amount
1 Jan 2013 100.00000
2 Feb 2013  94.91525
3 Mar 2013 105.08475
4 Apr 2013 100.00000
5 May 2013 100.00000
```

UPDATE: If memory is a problem use this for `explode` instead.  It aggregates within `explode` first so that its output is smaller.  Also we have eliminated the `dates` column in `DF` as it was only included for debugging:

```
explode <- function(start, end, amount) {
   dates <- seq(start, end, "day")
   DF <- data.frame(yearmon = as.yearmon(dates), amount = amount / length(dates))
   aggregate(amount ~ yearmon, DF, sum)
}
```

UPDATE 2:  Here is another attempt.  It uses `rowsum` which is specialized for aggregating sums.  This one ran 10x faster on the data in the post in my test.

```
explode2 <- function(start, end, amount) {
  dates <- seq(start, end, "day")
  n <- length(dates)
  rowsum(rep(amount, n) / n, format(dates, "%Y-%m"))
}
by.date <- do.call("rbind", Map(explode2, df$start, df$end, df$amount))
rowsum(by.date, rownames(by.date))
```

Comment: I found this answer to be the most clear. I haven't come across do.call but after "spending a bit of time" I'm starting to understand this one. This answer has also improved my thinking around functional programming but I still have a long way to go before I can truly grasp the linked Flat Apportionment answers. Many Thanks All.