# Apportioning value over time based on date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

To preface my question, I did see the following link, and if it is the same query I fear my skills may be to primitive to confirm whether it is the case: [Flat Apportionment of values across time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835463/flat-apportionment-of-values-across-time-periods), any help would be appreciated.

Please bear with be as my programming skills are still relatively basic.

I was wondering if it was possible to equally apportion values over time based on a date field?

Data is based on enrolment units, with a number value for hours and start and end date values.

Eg: Row level data

| Unit Name | Department | Hours | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Electrical | 30 | 1/01/2021 | 31/03/2021 |
| DEF | Hospitality | 50 | 1/03/2021 | 31/04/2021 |

Then wanted to *equally* distribute the hours by month based on the end date

End result to display would be something like this:

**Total Hours by Department**

| Department | Jan 2021 | Feb 2021 | Mar 2021 | April 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Electrical | 10 | 10 | 10 |  |
| Hospitality |  |  | 25 | 25 |
| **Total** | **10** | **10** | **35** | **25** |

Is something like this even possible?

Again my skills are still basic and this may be a very stupid question. Apologies in advance.

Comment: Do you know the months?  Are t here always four?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for replying. 

Would just do columns for the calendar year. For example if a unit had a start date of 01/09/2021 to 01/01/2022 with 50 hours, then in that example would do:

Sep - 10
Oct - 10
Nov - 10
Dec - 10

And January allocation of the final 10 of 50 hours wouldn't be counted, hope that makes sense?